# Access to 5 GHz Wifi on old notebook

Tags: wireless

Lubuntu has now been installed on my old Acer notebook which only works on 2.4 GHz WiFi. At a retreat center only 5 GHz was available and I could not download my email. Suggestions for a solution would be very welcome.  I am 81 and a complete Ubuntu neophyte so keep replies simple, please. Thank you.

Comment: Providing release details is always helpful, but in my opinion the only solution is a USB 5Ghz wifi module that will allow your hardware to access the 5GHZ network. As I understand site rules however (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.

Comment: Do you know whether your laptop supports anything other than 2.4 GHz WiFi, i.e., whether this is a Lubuntu problem or an hardware issue?

Comment: I don't think this is a hardware recommendation question - it just so happens that the best/only(?) solution is to buy a piece of hardware

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a USB WiFi adapter with 5 GHz support, preferably for the current WiFi 6 standard.
Take care to choose an offer that explicitly states it will work with Linux.
(Most do, but there are a few black sheep.)